# Prohibit rotation of pages in PDF when using Ghostscript

Tags: php, pdf, rotation, orientation, ghostscript

I'm using GhostScript to change DPI and resize PDF-files from PHP using exec() function.
My commandline code looks like this:

```
gs  -o out.pdf  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=800 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1000 -dPDFFitPage -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook in.pdf
```

But one of my PDFs first page after this processing is rotated and cropped. If I add `-dFixedMedia` parameter it will be still rotated but not cropped. But some other pages will be rotated in this case.

I've also tried `-dOrient1=false` and `-dOrient1=true`... and `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`... It all didn't work... Maybe I'm not using it right...

Is it possible to prevent/prohibit any kind of rotation for all PDF-pages?

---

P.S.

First page of initial PDF:

[image: Initial]

First page  of PDF after processing without `-dFixedMedia`:
[image: After1]

First page  of PDF after processing WITH `-dFixedMedia`:
[image: After2]

---

**Update:**

Here is a link to this one page PDF file:
[PDF-File](http://www.sendspace.com/file/atvdft)

---

Answer (score 2):

Its not really possible to tell what's going on without seeing an example file. Normaally pdfwrite will preserve the various boxes from the input file, and especially the MediaBox.

If it was me, I would start by removing -dPDFSETTINGS from the command line, this sets a *lot* of options. I'd set the options I wanted individually. Note that because you have this last in the command line, it will potentially override any prior settings.

If you set AutoRotatePages to false, then pdfwrite doesn't attempt any kind of rotation of the output.

Comment: I would give you this PDF file but i'm not supposed to share any of files that are used for my work... so my hands are tied. And about AutoRotatePages setting to None - it doesn't work for this PDF file... but anyway thank you very much for your answer

Comment: You've already posted a picture of an offending page above, how about making a single page PDF of that ?

Comment: I've updated my question. I added a link to this single PDF file. hope it'll help. Thank you

Comment: For me the 1 page file does not exhibit rotation, does it do so for you  ? I also don't get any surprising cropping. What version of Ghostscript are you using ?

Comment: GS ver. 9.07. Try to resize it using ghostscript and my code for example...this is what I get - http://www.sendspace.com/file/qj7ir3 Yes, it's not rotating...but it is still cropped.

Comment: Well, I'm using the current code from the repository, for me using your command line does not cause either cropping or rotation. I'll try the released 9.07 and Linux tomorrow. Did you get this from our downloads or a package ? The package maintainers have been known to apply patches to Ghostscript with varying degrees of success.

Comment: As far as I know it was a package

Comment: Then I'd suggest checking the latest source out of the Git repository, building it, and trying that to see if it gets a different result.

Comment: I used `-dAutoRotatePages=false` and this solved a similar problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

`dPDFFitPage` scales and rotates for the best fit of the device size.

See the `dPSFitPage` option here https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm